# Openerp why these views not generating

Tags: xml, odoo, openerp-7

I have created this class for future enhancement and just tried to create tree and form view for that as usual. I can not find what I have done wrong and please help me to correct this since this won't generate any views.

***My dummy class***

```
  class leave_score(osv.osv):
_name = "leave.score"
_description=""

_columns = {

    'test1':fields.char('Test')
}
```

***Views for that class***

```
 <record id="view_leave_score_filter" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">leave.score.filter</field>
        <field name="model">leave.score</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <search string="Search Company Holidyas">
                <field name="test1" string="Leave Types"/>
            </search>
        </field>
    </record>


    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="edit_leave_score_form">
        <field name="name">leave.score.form</field>
        <field name="model">leave.score</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Leave Score" version="7.0">
                <field name="test1"/>
        </form>
        </field>
    </record>


    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_leave_score_tree">
        <field name="name">leave.score.tree</field>
        <field name="model">leave.score</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Leave Score">
                <field name="test1"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>



    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_normal_leave_score_tree">
        <field name="name">leave.score.normal.tree</field>
        <field name="model">leave.score</field>
       <field name="priority">35</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Leave Score">
               <field name="test1"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>



    <record id="view_leave_score_search" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">leave.score.search</field>
        <field name="model">leave.score</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <search string="Leave Score">
                <field name="test1"/>
            </search>
        </field>
    </record>


    <record id="open_view_leave_score" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Leave Score Card</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="res_model">leave.score</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        <field name="view_id" eval="view_normal_leave_score_tree"/>
        <field name="search_view_id" ref="view_leave_score_search"/>
    </record>       

    <menuitem name="Leave Score Cards" action="open_view_leave_score" id="menu_open_view_leave_score" parent="base.menu_reporting_dashboard"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have written model name in all views are "leave.core" but in class model name is "leave.score"

```
<field name="model">leave.core</field>

class leave_score(osv.osv):
    _name = "leave.score"
```

However these typo may raise an error while you installed that module if model name you have written wrong.

Make sure you have added that XML file into the **openerp**.py file. If it's not there then this xml code will not not create any views or actions  or menus.

Name must not be same for all views, which is same in your case. This may create an issue.

```
<field name="name">leave.score.filter</field>
```

Comment: Sorry that was my bad... I didn't notice it , actually I retyped my view in here to get the question shot and because of that I think I got that error... btw I have edited it out and thank you so much for the quick answer. apart from that have you figure out any error in this ?

Comment: Thank you sir/madam for your kind answer, but it still not working. I have updated the xml part and tried it again still not working

Comment: What you are getting in response ? Any error ? Can you please make sure whether all these views are created or not ? Settings => Technical => User Interface => Views. And please also make sure this xml file has been added in openerp.py file or not ?

Comment: Yes, I can see my interfaces on that list and yes I have used this same xml file before for another class.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, if you're creating a new model, and can't see any of the views, it's most likely because of the security privileges.

When I created this module based on the code you provided, I was only able to see it as the administrator.

[image]

In order to have other users see it, then you need to give access rights to the user groups that will be allowed to see it. You can do that by creating the "ir.model.access.csv" file, then add any groups and privileges that they will have.

In the example below, I am granting read, write, create, and unlink privileges to the Sales Manager group. You can add more lines for other groups, and remove privileges by changing the 1's to 0's

```
id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
access_leave_score_mngr,leave_score manager,model_leave_score,base.group_sale_manager,1,1,1,1
access_leave_score_user,leave_score user,model_leave_score,base.group_user,1,0,0,0
```

Make sure to register the ir.access.model.csv file in the __openerp__.py file like so

```
{
    'name': 'your module name',
    'version': '1.0',
    'summary': 'your summary',
    'description':'',
    'category': 'your category',
    'author': 'your name',
    'website': '',
    'depends': ['base' ],
    'data': [
        'name_of_view_file.xml',
        'ir.model.access.csv'],
    'js': [],
    'css': [],
    'installable': True,
    'auto_install': False,
}
```

You can also add privileges through the interface, but using the ir.model.access.csv file is the preferred way to do it. Also, most of the other modules will have the ir.model.access.csv file in a security folder, so then you would need to change the line in the __openerp__.py file from 'ir.model.access.csv' to 'security/ir.model.access.csv' if that is where you keep that file on your modules.